# Every parallelizable even dimensional manifold is symplectic?

Tags: solution-verification, symplectic-geometry

I am just thinking about this. So, we have the symplectic form on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}:\omega_o=\sum_{i=1}^{2n}dx_i\wedge dy_i,$ where $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n$ are linear coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}.$  We can just use this form to get a symplectic form on the manifold. Is this correct or am I making some mistake here?

**Edit:** In details what I mean is suppose we have $\phi:TM\rightarrow M\times\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ which gives us an diffeomorphism such that it gives us linear isomorphism on each tangent space level. Now my proposed symplectic form is the following: for $x\in M,v,w\in T_mM,\omega_x(v,w)=\omega_0(\pi_2\circ \phi(x,v),\pi_2\circ \phi(x,w))$ where $\pi_2$ is the projection onto $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ from $M\times\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample is $S^{1}\times S^{3}$. It does not have a symplectic structure because $H^{2}(S^{1}\times S^{3})=0$.

But $S^{1}\times S^{3}$ is parallelizable: both $S^{1}$ and $S^{3}$ are parallelizable since they are Lie groups, and the product of parallelizable manifolds is again parallelizable.

Comment: Yeah I totally missed that. But anyway $\omega$ in the question should still be non-degenerate, isn't it? I mean where does the proof goes wrong? It might not be closed though.

Comment: @Larsson I agree, $\omega$ is non-degenerate but there is no reason for it to be closed.